# remove validation message when user select cancel button in angular

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

I have enable angular form validations for my form and I can see corresponding error message on my screen  if my form is not valid.
I have another requirement. On same form ,I need to add cancel button which when clicked should empty my form field values. This I am able to achieve. My problem starts here.

When user enter some values in form fields and sbumit form  , validation messages appear But how to remove those message when click "Cancel button"?

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to help you without some specific code snippets to talk about

Answer (score 1):

On click event of Cancel button , i did $submitted = false which worked